# Is it important to delete unused columns?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database

My app includes two models that each have one column that the app is no longer using. I believe that I understand how to migrate them out of the database. And I don't think that it will take much work to migrate them out. But before I started working on that, I got curious. How much effect does each column have on the performance of the app? Are there other possible side-effects to leaving it there? I couldn't find these questions answered elsewhere.

Thanks for your thoughts,

Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does have effect:

1. It takes db space
2. Each time you're loading model, AR takes more resources to load all columns and create an object
3. Most of read/write actions will take a tiny bit more time because of excessive column.

While this won't be palpable for a user, I would definitely go with removing the no longer used column.

Comment: I agree with your response, so I'm asking this next question just to learn. Both answers so far mention that it takes up database space. What harm does that cause?

Answer (score 1):

You should remove it, the reason is

1. This will take db space even its not required
2. When some new guy will see and try to understand the usage of all column of this table, he might gets confused. So from readability and understanding point of view you should also remove the column. The column might also be part of triggers, stored procedures and indexes, so its important to clean up the unused column for a scalable product.

But remove it carefully, if it is being used in trigger, stored procedure and function then application might break.

Comment: I agree with your response, so I'm asking this next question just to learn. Both answers so far mention that it takes up database space. What harm does that cause?